# Can't create a function expected to be called in the end of an execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, web-scraping

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to create a function which will be called in the end of an execution no matter whether any error the other functions encounter. To be more specific - there is a function `bound_to_call()` in the following example which needs to be called automatically once the execution is accomplished or interrupted. There is method in scrapy `def close(spider, reason)` which does exactly what I tried to describe.

I want to save excel workbook using this function `bound_to_call()` because the workbook comes into existence when this line is called `wb.save('SO.xlsx')`. However, that very line is usually called in the end and if it is not called there will be no workbook even when the script scrapes most of the results.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from openpyxl import Workbook

link = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"

def get_info(s,link):
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select(".summary"):
        user = item.select_one(".user-details > a").get_text(strip=True)
        title = item.select_one(".question-hyperlink").get_text(strip=True)
        ws.append([user,title])
        print(user,title)

def bound_to_call():
    wb.save('SO.xlsx')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    wb = Workbook()
    wb.remove(wb['Sheet'])
    ws = wb.create_sheet('useractivity')
    ws.append(['name','title'])
    with requests.Session() as s:
        get_info(s,link)
    bound_to_call()
```

> Question: How can I call a function in the end of an execution no matter whether there is any error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the python `Exception` forms to capture errors, ie. `try:` and `except:`
Here is code (py3) with Exception handling:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        wb = Workbook()
    except Exception as err:
        print("Error on creating workbook", err)
        exit()

    try:
        wb.remove(wb['Sheet'])
        ws = wb.create_sheet('useractivity')
        ws.append(['name','title'])
        with requests.Session() as s:
            get_info(s,link)
    except Exception as err:
        print("Error scraping website", err)

    # This will be called so long as wb is instanciated. 
    bound_to_call()
```